# jboss clustering GMS, join

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing

I have jboss 5.1.0.

we have configured jboss somehow using clustering, but in fact we do not use clustering while developing or testing. But in order to launch the project i have to type the following:

> ./run.sh -c all -g uniqueclustername
>   -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.messaging.ServerPeerID=1 -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01

but while jboss starting i able to see something like this in the console:

> 17:24:45,149 WARN  [GMS]
>   join(172.24.224.7:60519) sent to
>   172.24.224.2:61247 timed out (after 3000 ms), retrying 17:24:48,170 WARN 
>   [GMS] join(172.24.224.7:60519) sent to
>   172.24.224.2:61247 timed out (after 3000 ms), retrying 17:24:51,172 WARN 
>   [GMS] join(172.24.224.7:60519)

here 172.24.224.7 it is my local IP
though 172.24.224.2 other IP of other developer in  our room (and jboss there is stoped).

So, it tries to join to the other node or something. (i'm not very familiar how jboss acts in clusters). And as a result the application are not starting.

What may be the problem in? how to avoid this joining ?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably fix this by specifying

```
-Djgroups.udp.ip_ttl=0
```

in your startup.  This Sets the IP time-to-live on the JGroups packets to zero, so they never get anywhere, and the cluster will never form. We use this in dev here to stop the various developer machines from forming a cluster. There's no need to specify a unique cluster name.

I'm assuming you need to do clustering in production, is that right?  Could you just use the `default` configuration instead of `all`?  This would remove the clustering stuff altogether.

Comment: no i can not use not 'all' (it is configured somehow as well, it uses a lot of services inside). i will try this tomorrow and will let you know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

while setting up the server, keeping the `host name = localhost` and `--host=localhost` instead of ip address will solve the problem. That makes the server to start in non clustered mode.